# How to load multiple js files after the loading of html page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load 6 js files after the loading of the html page. One of those 6 files is jquery file and the other 5 are jquery dependent. I'm loading jquery file first but still getting an error "$ is not defined". Its working fine when I load jquery file initially in the head section and then the other 5 files after the load. Pls tell me why it is happening like that.

Comment: Please provide your `HTML` code incluing your `<script>` tags, it seems that you are trying to load some js files that requires jQuery before you load the jQuery lib.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, you said that it works fine when you load the jquery file initially in the head section and the other files after? Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill : I dont want my jquery file to be loaded before the load of the page.

Comment: @mgamon : errors in console showing only those file names which i'm trying to load after the loading of html.

Comment: Remember to include the code that you are using, when asking questions. Without it we cannot give you good answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about using window.load which is fired after $(document).ready()?

```
$(window).load(function()
{
   document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/yourscript1\"></scr" + "ipt>");
   document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/yourscript2\"></scr" + "ipt>");
});
```

Since you have not loaded jQuery, would this do it for you?:

In your html

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

and then in the script (You also load your jQuery)

```
function myFunction()
{
   document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/yourscript1\"></scr" + "ipt>");
   document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/js/yourscript2\"></scr" + "ipt>");
});
```

Comment: In order to $(document).ready() to get fired, we need to load jquery js first right?

Comment: Sorry. Thought you already had loaded jquery. I'll add more to my answer.